# Swift variable inheritance in protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a struct that contains an enum variable (here x) and should conform to a protocol (here A). The enum variable itself is an implementation of a protocol which is also used in the protocol A. But somehow the struct does not conform to the protocol according to the compiler.
Can you help me and explain why this is happening and how it could be solved?
Thanks a lot for the help!

```
protocol A {
    var x: String { get }
}

protocol B {
  var x: A { get }
}

enum C: A {
    var x: String {
        return ""
    }
}

struct D: B { // <- Type 'D' does not conform to protocol 'B'
  var x: C
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new `any` syntax in Swift 5.7 hopefully will make this a little clearer. The explicit way to write `B` is:

```
protocol B {
  var x: any A { get }
}
```

`B` says that the thing returned from `x` is an "existential" (any) type. It's a wrapper around `A` that is of a specific, known size. `C` is not that. It may have a different size that is not the same as an existential wrapper.

The return type of `x` must be `any A`. It cannot just be something that conforms to `A`. If you want each B-conforming type to have its own version, then you would use an `associatedtype`:

```
protocol B {
  associatedtype X: A
  var x: X { get }
}
```

With that, `D` can conform. But there will also be some restrictions put on how you can use `B` (it becomes a more complicated type), so you should think hard about if this is really your goal. Almost always the correct way to design your protocols is to start with what kind of code will *use* this protocol, rather than starting with what kind of code will *implement* this protocol. Starting will the calling code will lead you to what kinds of protocols you really need.

As a side note, your question title suggests you believe that C inherits from A. That's not correct. Structs cannot inherit from anything. A *conforms* to C. Conforming to a protocol is not the same thing as inheriting from a superclass. In particular, it has situations like this one. Conforming is better thought of as something attached to a type, to allow the type to participate in general-purpose algorithms. It does not fundamentally define what the type is in the way that class inheritance does. Conformance can be attached to a type retroactively, even in another module and without even having access to the type's source code. (I could make `String` or `CBPeripheral` conform to `B` just as easily as `D`.)